# LaTex image problem

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, measure

I'm trying to add an image into my text, but with **the most simple method**.

**This is not the whole code**, but I just wanted to show you what I used. I used this same method before in one template and it worked. Now I get 6 errors, all listed on the places they appeared on:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

     \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5pt\textwidth} % Environment wrapfigure undefined and Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
        \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=7cm]{img1.jpg} % Undefined control sequence
         \captionog{figure}{Blind Date (Mein mit dem leben)}
      \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure} % \begin{document} ended by \end{wrapfigure}
```

What should I do? I need a **very simple and short method** since this is only small practice project.
I want this photo to appear on the right side of the text with small spacing between text and image.

When I added `\usepackage{wrapfig}` and tried to insert image like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    \caption{Karava\dj{}o - autoportret}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=7cm]{img1.jpg}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I got this (there is only text and subsection after image code):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is hard to be sure what is causing the problem without a complete, compilable example. Nevertheless, looking at the warnings, I'd guess that your figure simply doesn't fit where you're trying to place it (``wrapfigure``s can be somewhat capricious about placing). I would begin by trying to move it in the code to see if it can be placed elsewhere.